how to apply theme to mtx-date-picker in angular
I'm using ng-matero/extensions or more popularly known as Angular Material Extensions library. I want to use the DateTimePicker component. My problem is the component is not picking up the theme color.
Currently my implementation looks like this:

As you can see it is not picking the proper theme colors and the background color of the panel and text colors are off. How can I fix this issue.
In HTML file of the component I have done:


<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label for="toTime">To [Date & Time]</mat-label>
  <mtx-datetimepicker #toDatetimePicker [type]="type" [mode]="mode" [twelvehour]="twelvehour" [timeInterval]="timeInterval" [timeInput]="timeInput"></mtx-datetimepicker>
  <input id="toTime" [mtxDatetimepicker]="toDatetimePicker" formControlName="endTime" matInput required />
  <mtx-datetimepicker-toggle [for]="toDatetimePicker" matSuffix></mtx-datetimepicker-toggle>
</mat-form-field>



In scss file of the component I have done:


@use "@ng-matero/extensions" as matx;
@use "../../m3-theme.scss" as custom-theme;
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  @include matx.all-component-themes(custom-theme.$mtx-theme);
}



Here, mtx-theme is a angular material3 theme.


$mtx-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: dark,
      primary: $_primary,
      tertiary: $_tertiary,
    ),
  )
);



colors are properly defined here. I can say the theme is working because I'm using the same color theme for the whole app.
In TS file of the component I have:


export class MetricsRealtimeDataIngestionComponent implements OnInit {
  type: MtxDatetimepickerType = 'datetime';
  mode: MtxDatetimepickerMode = 'auto';
  twelvehour: boolean = true;
  timeInterval: number = 1;
  timeInput: boolean = true;
  // ... other stuff
}



